# rails, whenever and docker - cron tasks doesn't run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, cron, whenever

My crontasks from `schedule.rb` doesn't work on docker container, but  `crontab -l` result already contains this lines:

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /app/config/schedule.rb
45 19 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'bundle exec rake stats:cleanup'
45 19 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'bundle exec rake stats:count'
0 5 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'bundle exec rake stats:history'
# End Whenever generated tasks for: /app/config/schedule.rb
```

I can run this commands manually in container and it works. It seems like cron doesn't start.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.4.0-slim
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -qq -y --no-install-recommends build-essential libpq-dev cron postgresql-client
RUN cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Moscow /etc/localtime
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV RAILS_ENV production
ENV INSTALL_PATH /app
RUN mkdir $INSTALL_PATH
RUN touch /log/cron.log
ADD Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH
RUN bundle install --binstubs --without development test
COPY . .
RUN bundle exec whenever --update-crontab
RUN service cron start
ENTRYPOINT ["bundle", "exec", "puma"]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a Dockerfile, the RUN command is only execute when building the image.

If you want to start cron when you start your container, you should run `cron` in `CMD`. I modified your Dockerfile by removing `RUN service cron start` and changing your `ENTRYPOINT`.

```
FROM ruby:2.4.0-slim
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -qq -y --no-install-recommends build-essential libpq-dev cron postgresql-client
RUN cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Moscow /etc/localtime
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV RAILS_ENV production
ENV INSTALL_PATH /app
RUN mkdir $INSTALL_PATH
RUN touch /log/cron.log
ADD Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH
RUN bundle install --binstubs --without development test
COPY . .
RUN bundle exec whenever --update-crontab
CMD cron && bundle exec puma
```

It's a best practice to reduce the number of layer an image have, for example, you should always combine RUN apt-get update with apt-get install in the same RUN statement, and clean apt files after: `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`

```
FROM ruby:2.4.0-slim
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -qq -y --no-install-recommends build-essential libpq-dev cron postgresql-client \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
  cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Moscow /etc/localtime
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV RAILS_ENV production
ENV INSTALL_PATH /app
RUN mkdir $INSTALL_PATH && \
  touch /log/cron.log
ADD Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH
RUN bundle install --binstubs --without development test
COPY . .
RUN bundle exec whenever --update-crontab
CMD cron && bundle exec puma
```